# Detect facebook app user is on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

How can I determine if a user is looking at my website from their facebook app?

I am using backbone and would like to serve a different route if a user is in fact looking at the website from their fb app.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question you asked here - that's about how to detect Facebook's user agent used by the crawler

Comment: so i'm seeing... thanks for the follow up. thought perhaps if I could pickup the facebook user agent I'd be set ...

Comment: There is no 'Facebook user agent' outside the context of the crawler which fetches metadata from shared URLs - the user's browser makes the request to your site when your site is being accessed via it being an canvas app or page tab app on Facebook.com - what are you trying to detect, exactly?

Comment: only if they are within their facebook app looking at my website. so if they were using their facebook app, and found a fb post with my website link, they get sent to it, but it's within facebook's app which doesn't allow you to rotate, I'm trying to pick that up so i can serve a different experience accordingly.

Comment: Oh, so you want the user agent for the Facebook for iPhone or Facebook for Android app's webviews? easiest thing to do there would be to open something like this in the app: whatsmyuseragent.com